# Check if draggable Object is in correct droppable container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have items, which I can drag and drop around. Now, after I dropped the Item, I want to check if my object is in the correct container.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

This here is my function for it:

```
$(function () {
    $("#draggable").draggable();
    $(".item").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.append(ui.draggable);

            var draggableWidth = $('#draggable').width();
            var draggableHeight = $('#draggable').height();
            var width = $this.width();
            var height = $this.height();
            var cntrLeft = (width / 2) - (ui.draggable.width() / 2);
            var cntrTop = (height / 2) - (ui.draggable.height() / 2);

            ui.draggable.animate({width: draggableWidth * 1.1, height: draggableHeight * 1.1});
            ui.draggable.animate({width: draggableWidth, height: draggableHeight});
            ui.draggable.css({
                left: cntrLeft + "px",
                top: cntrTop + "px"
            });

            // this here is still hard-coded, but it should trigger on the element I'm holding (image)
            console.log($('#draggable4').data('image'));
            console.log($(this).data('target'));
        }
    });
});
```

If you take a look at this example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/F3sD3/) you can see, what I'm actually stuck with. You can move the yellow square in the boxes, but there is no feedback if it is the correct one.

To clarify it a bit more: Lets say I have 2 squares, a yellow and a red one. If the yellow square is dropped on the left box, it should display an error. Otherwise a tick-symbol should appear (not that kind of a problem). 
Same goes for the red one. If the red one is dropped in the right box, it should throw an error... you get the point.

**Update 1:**

My HTML

```
<div class="item" data-target="1"></div>
<div class="item2" data-target="2"></div>
<div class="item3" data-target="3"></div>
<div class="item4" data-target="4"></div>

<div style="position: relative; height: 100%;">
    <img src="folie1/img1.png" width="153" height="124" id="draggable" style="z-index: 200;" data-image="1"/>
    <img src="folie1/img2.png" width="153" height="124" id="draggable2" style="z-index: 201;" data-image="2"/>
    <img src="folie1/img3.png" width="153" height="124" id="draggable3" style="z-index: 202;" data-image="3"/>
    <img src="folie1/img4.png" width="153" height="124" id="draggable4" style="z-index: 203;" data-image="4"/>
</div>
```

I want to check if the current object (lets say `data-image="1"`) is dropped in the container `data-target="1"`.

**Update 2**

This is my HTML now:

```
<div class="item" id="item" data-target="1"></div>
<div class="item" id="item2" data-target="2"></div>
<div class="item" id="item3" data-target="3"></div>
<div class="item" id="item4" data-target="4"></div>

<div style="position: relative; height: 100%;">
    <img src="folie1/img1.png" width="153" height="124" id="draggable" class="draggable"
         style="z-index: 200;" data-image="1"/>
    <img src="folie1/img2.png" width="153" height="124" id="draggable2" class="draggable"
         style="z-index: 201;" data-image="2"/>
    <img src="folie1/img3.png" width="153" height="124" id="draggable3" class="draggable"
         style="z-index: 202;" data-image="3"/>
    <img src="folie1/img4.png" width="153" height="124" id="draggable4" class="draggable"
         style="z-index: 203;" data-image="4"/>
</div>
```

... with the JS from Rajen Ranjith

```
$(function () {
    var result = {};
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        start: function (e) {
            result.drag = e.target.id.split("_")[1];
        }
    });
    $(".item").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {

            var $this = $(this);
            result.drop = event.target.id.split("_")[1];
            if (result.drag == result.drop)
                alert("true");
            else
                alert("false");
            $this.append(ui.draggable);

            var width = $this.width();
            var height = $this.height();
            var cntrLeft = (width / 2) - (ui.draggable.width() / 2);
            var cntrTop = (height / 2) - (ui.draggable.height() / 2);

            ui.draggable.css({
                left: cntrLeft + "px",
                top: cntrTop + "px"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I can drag and drop my images, but it always alerts "true".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use id or attributes for both drag element and drop element
http://jsfiddle.net/rajen_ranjith/F3sD3/285/

```
$(function() {
var result = {};
$(".draggable").draggable({
    start:function(e){
        result.drag = e.target.id.split("_")[1];
    }
});
$(".item").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {

        var $this = $(this);
        result.drop = event.target.id.split("_")[1];
        if(result.drag == result.drop)
            alert("true");
         else
            alert("false");
        $this.append(ui.draggable);    

        var width = $this.width();
        var height = $this.height();
        var cntrLeft = (width / 2) - (ui.draggable.width() / 2);
        var cntrTop = (height / 2) - (ui.draggable.height() / 2);

        ui.draggable.css({
            left: cntrLeft + "px",
            top: cntrTop + "px"
        });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: I like the idea, but this produces an error? SyntaxError: missing } after function body

Comment: nvm. Was a mistake by me. But now it shows "true" everytime. See updated question

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this by using the data-attribute in the dropable div, as described [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/). You can check the data-value with jQuery like [this](http://api.jquery.com/data/). The data-attribute could than be checked against a data-attribute on the draggable div. If equal, it could be the correct one.

Comment: I tried to add the attributes, and it kinda works, but I have no idea on how to get the data-attr of the current object i'm dragging. I'll update the question